# Get array data and insert into database

Tags: arrays, codeigniter, csv

I'm trying to get the data in the array that came from another function(that function is extracting the data in the csv file) and when i tried calling the two fields from that array it shows an error that it is ***unidentified variables***.

The `$this->csv_process();` as shown on the function action() is the function that extracts the data from the csv file and stores it in an array which is successful since I tried checking it on `var_dump();`

I also named the two fields as $name and $email as shown below:

Function CSV_process()

```
public function csv_process()
    {
        /* variables for openning the csv file */                        

            if (!in_array($extension, $allowed_ext)) {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata("message", "Sorry, CSV file only.");            
            } else {
                if ($filesize > 0) {
                $file         = fopen($filename, "r");
                $toWrite     = array();        
                $error         = false;
                $col_size     = 2;
                $skip         = 0;                                
                    while ($data = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ","))
                    {
                        $skip++;
                        if ($skip == 1) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        $numofcol = count($data);
                        if ($numofcol != $col_size ) {
                            $this->session->set_flashdata("message", "Column count exceeded or missing.");
                        } else {
                            $name1         = $data[0];
                            $name         = str_replace("'", "''", $name1);
                            $email1     = $data[1];
                            $email         = str_replace("'", "''", $email1);
                            $toWrite[]    = [
                                        'name'  => $name,
                                        'email' => $email
                            ];    
                        }                        
                    }
                }
            }

            return $toWrite;
    }
```

Function Action()

```
function action(){
$toWrite[] = $this->csv_process();
    foreach ($toWrite as $arr) {
        list($name, $email) = $arr;
        //die(var_dump($arr));
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM import WHERE name ='$name'  AND email = '$email'");
        if ($query->num_rows() >= 1) {

        } else {
            if ($name == "" OR $email == "") {
            } else {
                if ((filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) == FALSE ) {
                } else {
                    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO import(name, email, created_date) VALUES('".$name."', '".$email."', '".date("Y-m-d h-i-s")."')");
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'SUCCESS YEAY');
                    redirect('Clean_csv/index');
                }
            }
        }
        $query->free_result();
    }
 }
```

Listing arrays doesn't seem to work for here, anyone knows how to extract the data array from ***$arr?***

Comment: Does anyone know how the data look like in `$arr`? Nobody knows except you so please... You've a `die(var_dump($arr));` line in your code - comment this out and post the content pls...

Comment: @sintakonte, Look at the code. The structure of `$arr` is `['name'  => "value",  'email' => 'email_value']`

Comment: @sintakonte Sorry but as you can see it's already in comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to extract the values. You can use each `$arr` in a [bound query](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html#query-bindings). It simplifies the syntax for the select query.

For inserting use CodeIgniter's [`insert()`](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#inserting-data) method. Again, the `$arr` can be used directly by adding the `date` to it before the insert is attempted.

I think this will work.

```
function action()
    {
        $toWrite[] = $this->csv_process();
        foreach($toWrite as $arr)
        {
            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM import WHERE name=?  AND email=?", $arr);
            if($query->num_rows() >= 1)
            {}
            else
            {
                if($arr['name'] == "" OR $arr['email'] == "")
                {}
                else
                {
                    if((filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) == FALSE)
                    {}
                    else
                    {
                        $arr['created_date'] = date("Y-m-d h-i-s");
                        $this->db->insert("import", $arr);
                        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'SUCCESS YEAY');

                        //??? redirect('Clean_csv/index');  
                        //Are you sure, you may still have more $arr in $toWrite to process - right?
                    }
                }
            }
            $query->free_result();
        }
    }
```

You need to know what a terrible idea it is to repeatedly run database queries inside a loop. Even though you use `free_result()` it could be a massive drain on server resources. If your csv file has several thousand items you are severely stressing the database and the server.

Comment: Oh sorry, I've never knew it can stress the db and server.. but thanks for you tip! I'll mind it now. I'll try this solution and send you back the result right after. Thanks again for helping me.

Comment: But I have a little question, what you have shown me truly helps alot but I'm validating if data[0] which is name and data[1] which is the email does have values in it. Since we used bindings, the condition in 

if($name == "" OR $email == ""){}

had become an unidentified variables.

Comment: Yes, I see the problem. I didn't pay attention. The answer has been revised to handle that issue.